# How to maximize chrome browser in default when using selenium in python

Tags: python

When I run chrome driver from selenium the browser opens in minimized windows. but I want it to open by default as maximized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use 
driver.maximize_window() or 
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized") which will maximize the browser when ever it opens.

Answer (score 1):

The following code was taken from this link. https://pythonbasics.org/selenium-maximize/

```py
from selenium import webdriver 
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)

driver.get("https://www.python.org")
```

This is one of the methods to do so.