# Selenium does not open windows as maximized

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to open the maximized page, but selenium does not work. It just opens the page usually.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options    
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/Users/chromedriver', options=options)
```

Answer (score 2):

Per this post [How to maximize chrome browser in default when using selenium in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60507053/how-to-maximize-chrome-browser-in-default-when-using-selenium-in-python) you can try `chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")` and depending on your version of chromedriver, it's worth reading through this post: [How to maximize the browser window in Selenium WebDriver (Selenium 2) using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189430/how-to-maximize-the-browser-window-in-selenium-webdriver-selenium-2-using-c)

`driver.maximize_window()` also seems to be an option to try.

Comment: driver.maximize_window() is working, but how to maximize the window using chrome options?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean `--start-fullscreen`?

Comment: It is very good answer but fullscreen is different from maximize.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this `options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")`

Comment: This also works, but I need to do it without giving it display resolution.

Answer (score 0):

The `--` shouldn't be there.
The correct syntax is:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
```

Comment: Actually, I don't use the selenium service because of its requirement to check the latest version of the chromedriver every time. Removing -- does not work.

Comment: You don't have to use service. I just pasted the code that is 100% working. Your problem is redundant '--' as I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

And in C# it will be `Driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();`.